# Create virtual keyboard in PyQt

Tags: button, layout, pyqt

I am trying to have a `QWidget` mimicking an Italian Apple Magic Keyboard layout (portrayed in the figure) in PyQt5.

I tried looking for some code online but I have only found QML code (I am not familiar with it) or very long C++ code implementing more that just a bunch of buttons.
So, I tried implementing the keyboard myself, but I failed (details on the unsuccessful attempts below).

[image: An Italian Apple Magic Keyboard from above]

These are the crucial points that make this task less trivial that what it may look.

- I would like the keys to maintain their aspect ratio (squares must remain squares). If I resize the window containing the keyboard, then the keyboard should have the size of the maximal rectangle contained in the window and preserving the aspect ratio of the keys (so one cannot use fixed lengths, but must work with ratios).
- There must be some space between the keys, and the ratio between the length of the side of a square key and the space must always remain constant, say 8:1.
- The up and down arrow keys, and especially the return key, are exceptional keys which probably require some add-hoc code. A workaround for the return key could be to split it into two keys, then add a custom SVG file to be sure that the common border is invisible and connect the two buttons so that when one is pressed also the one gets programmatically pressed.
- In general, the keys are not disposed in a grid, but in 6 rows, and each row is quite different, and shifted horizontally, from the others.

First I tried using a `QGridLayout` but I have soon realized that it cannot generalize complex non-grid scenarios, like in my case.

So, I have tried using one `QVBoxLayout` containing 6 `QHBoxLayout` and then treating each of these 6 rows independently. The problem was that I have not been able to specify the aspect ratio for the buttons of a particular row. E.g. the second row from the top has 13 square buttons, and 1 more button of width/height ratio of 1.5:1. 
I tried the two following possibility for specifying a button with a particular aspect ratio, but none of these (and slightly different variations) worked. In the first case I get wrong layouts. I have tried playing with the `QSizePolicy` but I have not been able to get the desired result. In the second case the `widthForHeight` function is never called. The problem may be that `ConstrainedButton` is not a subclass of `QGraphicsLayout` (I am not sure what this class is supposed to be used for). I haven't posted the rest of my code, I simply adds these button in a list of 6 `QHBoxLayout` enclosed in a `QVBoxLayout`.

Method 1:

```
class ConstrainedButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, base_width, base_height, *__args):
        super().__init__(*__args)
        size_policy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Ignored)
        self.setSizePolicy(size_policy)
        self.base_width = base_width
        self.base_height = base_height

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        new_size = QtCore.QSize(self.base_width, self.base_height)
        new_size.scale(event.size(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        self.resize(new_size)
```

Method 2:

```
class ConstrainedButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, width_for_height, *__args):
        super().__init__(*__args)
        self.width_for_height = width_for_height
        size_policy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Ignored)
        size_policy.setWidthForHeight(True)
        self.setSizePolicy(size_policy)

    def widthForHeight(self, height):
        return height * self.width_for_height
```

I am not sure this is the best approach. In asking for your help I am not asking you to write the full keyboard, it is a boring and long process to specify all the correct sizes, but it would be great to know how to code a small keyboard which addresses the 5 critical points listed above.

Comment: You could place the proportions of the buttons since there are buttons that are difficult to know their proportions, for example the escape key is easy to know its ratio: 1.5: 1 but what is the ratio of the enter key or the key that is to A's left? On the other hand, why don't you **use** (It is not necessary to implement anything) the [Qt Virtual Keyboard](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtvirtualkeyboard-index.html) or the [QtFreeVirtualKeyboard](https://github.com/githubuser0xFFFF/QtFreeVirtualKeyboard)?

Comment: @eyllanesc it would be cool to have an exact mirror of the layout I am using (even if it is not necessary). But one thing that is important for me is to be able to interactively modify the background color and the text of the keys (for instance adding a short text below the letter). If the Qt Virtual Keyboard is flexible enough I will try it

Comment: You have not provided me with the proportions that I have asked you to try to help you

Comment: @eyllanesc, ah sorry! I actually don't know all the proportions, My plan was first to make my code working with arbitrary proportions and then sit and look carefully at the keyboard to get better values.

Comment: My idea is to use QGridLayout obviously that I have to set certain properties that it seems that you don't use for what I need those proportions. 1) I have a doubt, let's assume that the ratio is 3:4 and say that the user changes the width then I suppose you want the height to change, the same I suppose you want it to happen if you modify the height, but if the user modifies both at the same time (by pressing the lower right corner of the window and dragging it) What should happen in that case?

Comment: 2) On the other hand, when I used the on-screen keyboard, it did not allow me to change the size of this one, but rather it sets a fixed size. Why do you want to give that characteristic to your keyboard?

Comment: @eyllanesc say that the keyboard ratio is 16:9, then no matter how one resize the window, there will one and only one maximal (and centered with respect to the window) rectangle with ratio 16:9. So there will be a unique way to portray the keyboard in there. I want the keyboard to be the largest as possible for the current screen, that's why fixed pixels size would not work, but only ratios.

Comment: Do you want the size of the keyboard to occupy the maximum area of the screen keeping the proportion? If so, then the simplest thing is to obtain the screen size, then calculate that maximum rectangle and then set the fixed size, don't you think that is easier?

Comment: @eyllanesc the approach that I was trying was exactly that, by specifying that the height of each button should have been maximum and by constraining the width to be a function of the height, but none of the two code snippets that try to implement this work.

Comment: mmm, I have not indicated that, I recommend you to re-read my comment. Is the size of the keyboard constant or what does it depend on?

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes, I want the keyboard to occupy maximum area of the screen keeping the proportions.

Comment: I explain myself in more detail: If the ratio between width-height of keyboard  is constant and you want it to occupy the maximum area within the screen, then the width and height is known so if the space between buttons is established then also the width and height of each button is fixed. That is, given the width and height of the screen and the space between buttons, then you can calculate the exact and fixed dimensions of each button. Isn't it easier to set those fixed dimensions to each button?

Comment: @eyllanesc aaaaah ok, right, how did I miss this. Yes this is a good approach. I will try. Do you think that this would lead to poor performance when resizing compared to the approach in which one passes ratios and let Qt optimize the resizing?

Comment: I think my method is simple.

Comment: @eyllanesc ok I will try and give you feedback, thanks!